# Jboss throwing IllegalStateException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss

I'm trying to launch a web application through my local. I have a separate war to generate PDF. When I hit my application and try to create a PDF of the report for my application information, while the action is forwarded from my application war to the PDF generator war I'm getting the error:

`SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet livexpactionservlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException`

Due to this everything is failing. I'm using jboss.4.0.3

JDK 1.5.0_22

Please let me know how to proceed

I have added the whole exception stack:

```
SEVERE: Invalid path /jsp/errors/notAuthorized.jsp?nonSecure=true was requested
13:53:58,440 INFO  [STDOUT] Apr 5, 2013 1:53:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet livexpactionservlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:423)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:125)
        at livexp.ui.web.BaseLiveXPRequestProcessor.processException(BaseLiveXPRequestProcessor.java:368)
        at livexp.ui.web.BaseLiveXPRequestProcessor.process(BaseLiveXPRequestProcessor.java:598)
        at livexp.ui.web.EnhancedLiveXPActionServlet.process(EnhancedLiveXPActionServlet.java:316)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:697)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at livexp.ui.web.SetCookieFilter.doFilter(SetCookieFilter.java:31)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at livexp.ui.web.MarkupFilter.doFilter(MarkupFilter.java:30)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter.doFilter(CASFilter.java:404)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.CustomPrincipalValve.invoke(CustomPrincipalValve.java:39)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:159)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:59)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:744)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Comment: can you please share the detailed log of the exception from log file? and this title is not suitable too.This is not JBOSS exception but it is your application exeception?can you tell us that Is this exception was coming at the time of development? or started coming after deployment?

Comment: mostly this exception comes when you try to write a response before commiting.In simple words you tried to use sendRedirect method for the HttpServletResponse.

Comment: hi i have added the exception stack .

Comment: see the first line `Invalid path /jsp/errors/notAuthorized.jsp`.do you have any notAuthorized.jsp? if yes then check its path

Comment: hi the jsp, exists.....n the path is same!!!

Comment: As you say yes then Believe that server is unable to find this file at this path.Try to set right path(interpretable by server) and then check

Comment: i m doing the same....my question is..... server is not able to find the file,  so its showing the illegal state exception?

Comment: yes, among many other reasons, this is a reason too

Comment: i m facing same problem even after placing the files according to server recognition!!!!

Comment: JBoss can throw this exception when handling too large of files (which is configurable). I've recently had IllegalArgumentException thrown because of this. When you try to genereate your PDF use a small file and see if the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

> the action is forwarded from my application war to the PDF generator
>   war I'm getting the error

So you're trying to forward the request from one .war to another? That's not going to work, they are separate applications. You need to either configure a shared context or send the client a redirect to that other .war. Or combine the apps to single war.